# XSLT firefox uri issue

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt

I am working with xml/xsl and I've implemented a link. The link is referencing another xml file. With the firefox browser I'm unable to open the link.
I've been searching on the net and found that you've got to add `file://` to the link.

*That is working really well for absolute paths, but with relative paths it is not able to resolve the link.*

Example Code:

file1.xml in the folder D:/try

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///D:/try/layout.xsl"?>
   <s1>
     <s>
      <uri>D:/tt.xml</uri>
     </s>
   </s1>
```

layout.xsl in the folder D:/try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <xsl:element name="body">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="s1"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="s1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="s"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="s">
    <table>
      <tr><th>Uri: </th><td>
        <xsl:element name="a">
          <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></xsl:attribute>
          <div><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></div>
        </xsl:element>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

tt.xml in the folder D:/try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s1>
  <s>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
  </s>
</s1>
```

If you replace the uri `D:/tt.xml` in file1.xml with the relative path `tt.xml` it is working.

**I'd like to have a function that converts the uri to an acceptable format.**

Regards,
Marky

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Consider to post some code or a URL to a test case demonstrating the problem. `resolve-uri` is not part of XSLT 1.0, the version of XSLT that current browsers support so don't expect that function to work within Firefox or other browsers.

Comment: Could you give an example of some XML that is supposed to work, but not working?

Comment: So you are transforming XML with XSLT to HTML and in the HTML relative links don't work with Firefox? What does the error console of Firefox say in that case? Is Firefox's behaviour any different when you simply use a HTML document with a relative URL? Can you post a URL to a document where we can visit the problem?

Comment: Relative URL is working but for absolute it says "unknown protocol d" if the link is something like "D:/bla.txt". I will prepare a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I got this:

```
        <xsl:if test="regexp:match(uri, '^.[^:].*', 'g')">
          <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></xsl:attribute>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></div>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="regexp:match(uri, '.*:.*', 'g')">
          <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="concat('file://',uri)"/>        
            </xsl:attribute>
            <div><xsl:value-of select="uri"/></div>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
```

But I don't think that's the best solution.